# Why starting project (Run) in Android Studio triggers APK rebuild even if no changes were made?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I mean, we are in 2016 and this is not a Borland compiler. 
The point of Run operation is to start the package on device. If no changes are made since last run, just run the APK, but this Gradle thing cannot manage it and runs in whole project compile each time (2-3 minutes). Components are not recompiled, but the whole package construction takes that time.

I wonder how the whole world of Android developers tolerates this (and other quirks of gradle). I searched in Google and found no solution. Any hints to make it better?

Comment: Did the answer below solve your question? If it didn't I can still help! :)

Comment: Thank you for link, I think most methods are already being used in our project. If there is really "I can do anything about it", then your answer is the answer, but my problem is not solved.

Comment: Don't worry, I've struggled a lot too, I hate the build style in AS, it's downright dull and is slow as Trump's brain. But I however can now build my project, without instant run,  in 4 seconds using the tips in the link. You might need to vary with the values, and the build might take long the first time.

Comment: And note that if your computer is really good, instant run builds gradle in around 1 second. I was surprised.

Comment: So, did I solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything about it; Android Studio just has to rebuild every time. But in the newer versions of Android Studio, you can use Instant Run. This runs/debugs your applications by using a simpler Gradle build in a very fast matter.

---

Also, take a look at [this](http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2015/06/11/speeding-up-your-gradle-builds/) , which previously helped me to reduce my Gradle build from 45 to 7 seconds.